# oncreate() method of service is invoked when the application is killed. Why?

Tags: android, service

When my application starts, the service is started ( it starts a chronometer ) and then the activity is bounded to this service. When i kill the application, the onCreate() method of the service is invoked thus the chronometer restarts. Why onCreate() method is called ? I don't want my chronometer restarts, i want it to continue from where it left.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BoundService mBoundService;
    boolean mServiceBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView timestampText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timestamp_text);
        Button printTimestampButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.print_timestamp);
        Button stopServiceButon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_service);
        Button startServiceButon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_service);
        printTimestampButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mServiceBound) {
                    timestampText.setText(mBoundService.getTimestamp());
                }
            }
        });

        stopServiceButon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mServiceBound) {
                    unbindService(mServiceConnection);
                    mServiceBound = false;
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        BoundService.class);
                stopService(intent);
            }
        });

        startServiceButon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mServiceBound) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BoundService.class);
                    startService(intent);
                    bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                    mServiceBound = true;
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.v("mainactivity", "in onStart");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BoundService.class);
        startService(intent);
        bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mServiceBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mServiceBound) {
            unbindService(mServiceConnection);
            mServiceBound = false;
        }
    }

    private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mServiceBound = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            MyBinder myBinder = (MyBinder) service;
            mBoundService = myBinder.getService();
            mServiceBound = true;
        }
    };
}
```

BoundService.java

```
public class BoundService extends Service {
    private static String LOG_TAG = "BoundService";
    private IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();
    private Chronometer mChronometer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "in onCreate");
        mChronometer = new Chronometer(this);
        mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        mChronometer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "in onBind");
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "in onRebind");
        super.onRebind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "in onUnbind");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "in onDestroy");
        mChronometer.stop();
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
                - mChronometer.getBase();
        int hours = (int) (elapsedMillis / 3600000);
        int minutes = (int) (elapsedMillis - hours * 3600000) / 60000;
        int seconds = (int) (elapsedMillis - hours * 3600000 - minutes * 60000) / 1000;
        int millis = (int) (elapsedMillis - hours * 3600000 - minutes * 60000 - seconds * 1000);
        return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + millis;
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        BoundService getService() {
            return BoundService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="oiyioz.com.a13_local_bound_service_4.MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/truiton_sq" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/print_timestamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:text="Print Timestamp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timestamp_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/print_timestamp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop_service"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/print_timestamp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Stop Service" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_service"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stop_service"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Start Service" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think the problem is with your `mServiceBound` boolean variable. Try checking it for false when you are starting your service.

Comment: @VivekMishra , it does not work, onCreate() method of the service is called in all scenarios :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of onCreate() use onActivityCreated().
For further details use the [Official link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Comment: Your answer will be treated as a link only answer in review process. It would be better to add some details from that link to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you kill your application you are killing the entire process, not just the activity. So your service is also gone and when you restart your app it has no idea about the previous state. To resolve this you should somehow persist the state that you are interested in.